# How to close a frame on action event of a button from a different class?

Tags: java, swing, awt, frame

I have a designed a **control-frame** on 1 class which has `jbutton` components, I have coded like on action event of these components diff-diff frame get initialized.

For each frame there is a class. now when I press second `jbutton` from control-frame then have to close the `frame` (which has opened when I pressed first `jbutton` from control-frame).

Comment: So, what's the problem? What did you try?

Comment: *"For each frame there is a class."*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of frame instance as instance variable in main class. Then close that instance on clicking close button.

```
public void open(ActionEvent e) {
    frame = new  something.. // your frame
}

public void close(ActionEvent e) {
    frame.dispose();
}
```

Note: 
JFrame frame is global variable.

Answer (score 0):

write this in your button click linstener

```
 yourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```